# wp_nav_menu_objects foreach loop is only applying to first item in loop when trying to output ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF field for a menu item and using code provided by [ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/) I've tried looping through the menu items to output the icon. However the icon only appends to the first item in the loop.

This is what I have so far:

functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'icon_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);

function icon_wp_nav_menu_objects($items, $args)
{
  if ($args->theme_location == 'main-menu') {
    
    // loop
    foreach ($items as &$item) {

      // vars
      $icon = get_field('icon', $item);

      // append icon
      if ($icon) {
        $item->title .= ' <img src="' . $icon . '" width="40px">';
      }

      // return
      return $items;
    }
  }
}
```

When I `print_r($items)`, I get the following:

```
Array
  (
    [1] => WP_Post Object(
      [ID] => 297[post_author] => 1[post_date] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_date_gmt] => 2023 - 07 - 23 17: 19: 42[post_content] => [post_title] => [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish[comment_status] => closed[ping_status] => closed[post_password] => [post_name] => 297[to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_modified_gmt] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0[guid] => http: //website.local/?p=297
      [menu_order] => 1[post_type] => nav_menu_item[post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0[filter] => raw[db_id] => 297[menu_item_parent] => 0[object_id] => 208[object] => page[type] => post_type[type_label] => Page[url] => http: //website.local/menu-item/
      [title] => Menu Item [target] => [attr_title] => [description] => [classes] => Array(
        [0] => [1] => menu - item[2] => menu - item - type - post_type[3] => menu - item - object - page[4] => menu - item - has - children
      )

      [xfn] => [current] => [current_item_ancestor] => [current_item_parent] =>
    )

    [2] => WP_Post Object(
      [ID] => 298[post_author] => 1[post_date] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_date_gmt] => 2023 - 07 - 23 17: 19: 42[post_content] => [post_title] => [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish[comment_status] => closed[ping_status] => closed[post_password] => [post_name] => 298[to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_modified_gmt] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0[guid] => http: //website.local/?p=298
      [menu_order] => 2[post_type] => nav_menu_item[post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0[filter] => raw[db_id] => 298[menu_item_parent] => 297[object_id] => 208[object] => page[type] => post_type[type_label] => Page[url] => http: //website.local/blog/
      [title] => Blog [target] => [attr_title] => [description] => [classes] => Array(
        [0] => [1] => menu - item[2] => menu - item - type - post_type[3] => menu - item - object - page
      )

      [xfn] => [current] => [current_item_ancestor] => [current_item_parent] =>
    )

    [3] => WP_Post Object(
      [ID] => 296[post_author] => 1[post_date] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_date_gmt] => 2023 - 07 - 23 17: 19: 42[post_content] => [post_title] => [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish[comment_status] => closed[ping_status] => closed[post_password] => [post_name] => 296[to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_modified_gmt] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0[guid] => http: //website.local/?p=296
      [menu_order] => 3[post_type] => nav_menu_item[post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0[filter] => raw[db_id] => 296[menu_item_parent] => 297[object_id] => 289[object] => page[type] => post_type[type_label] => Page[url] => http: //website.local/page/
      [title] => Page[target] => [attr_title] => [description] => [classes] => Array(
        [0] => [1] => menu - item[2] => menu - item - type - post_type[3] => menu - item - object - page
      )

      [xfn] => [current] => [current_item_ancestor] => [current_item_parent] =>
    )

    [4] => WP_Post Object(
      [ID] => 55[post_author] => 1[post_date] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_date_gmt] => 2023 - 07 - 15 13: 46: 30[post_content] => [post_title] => How can we help ? [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish[comment_status] => closed[ping_status] => closed[post_password] => [post_name] => link - 1[to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13 : 30: 30[post_modified_gmt] => 2023 - 08 - 21 13: 30: 30[post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0[guid] => http: //website.local/link-1/
      [menu_order] => 4[post_type] => nav_menu_item[post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0[filter] => raw[db_id] => 55[menu_item_parent] => 0[object_id] => 55[object] => custom[type] => custom[type_label] => Custom Link[title] => Link [url] => https : //website.local/link/
      [target] => [attr_title] => [description] => [classes] => Array(
        [0] => [1] => menu - item[2] => menu - item - type - custom[3] => menu - item - object - custom[4] => menu - item - has - children
      )

      [xfn] => [current] => [current_item_ancestor] => [current_item_parent] =>
    )
)
```

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pfffttt I just had to move the return statement to the outside of the foreach loop.

from:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'icon_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);

function icon_wp_nav_menu_objects($items, $args)
{
  if ($args->theme_location == 'main-menu') {
    
    // loop
    foreach ($items as &$item) {

      // vars
      $icon = get_field('icon', $item);

      // append icon
      if ($icon) {
        $item->title .= ' <img src="' . $icon . '" width="40px">';
      }

      // return
      return $items;
    }
  }
}
```

to:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'icon_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);

function icon_wp_nav_menu_objects($items, $args)
{
  if ($args->theme_location == 'main-menu') {
    
    // loop
    foreach ($items as &$item) {

      // vars
      $icon = get_field('icon', $item);

      // append icon
      if ($icon) {

        $item->title .= ' <img src="' . $icon . '" width="30px">';
      }
    }
    
    //return
    return $items;
  }
}
```